# Do I need to add reference to EntityFramework.SqlServer in presentation Layer?

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm writing an `MVC` web application using 3 tiers, `Web, BLL and DAL`. I've chosen MVC 5 Code first approach for my needs. My context and model classes reside in DAL. I'm implementing the repository pattern in my BLL that gets data from DAL, loads the data into ViewModels and serves the requests from the Web layer.

WEB --> has reference to BLL

BLL --> Has reference to DAL (entity framework installed on BLL)

DAL --> (entity framework installed on DAL).

I have entity framework installed on both DAL and BLL because I use DBSet or IDBSet in those both layers.

Now, the problem is, when I run the application, i keep getting the below error. It doesn't go away unless I install the entity framework on the Web layer, which i'm hesitant to do. I do not like to add entity framework to the web layer unless i absolutely have to. But the `dll` that's killing it is `EntityFramework.SqlServer.`

ERROR:

```
No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient'. Make sure the provider is registered in the 'entityFramework' section of the application config file. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.
```

Please let me know if I can do this without having to install entity framework on my web layer. Any input is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The way that I understand it, is that when you use MVC, each layer will be independent of the other (meaning that certain dependencies, such as catering for a particular DB engine, should not bubble up to the view layer, as per your dilemma).

If I am understanding your question correctly, you are saying that you have Database related data sets in your Middle Tier as well. I *think* that this is not the way to go since you are *constraining* your middle tier to use database related data structures.

The way I see it, should not be a problem for the `DAL` to internally use database oriented data structures internally, however, it should interact with the other segments of your system  through the use of *traditional* data structures such as Lists and Sets.

The same applies for the middle tier. If you do this, you should be able to keep entity framework reference requirements contained within your data layer. An everything would be self contained (reference wise).

Answer (score 0):

You should have all references in composition root. In your application composition root is web layer so you should add this reference to project. But you should not use its classes in web layer.